# Is there a term to describe how each 3d rotation matrix can be reordered to form the other?

Tags: linear-algebra

Each 3d rotation matrix Rx, Ry, Rz can have its row and column vectors shifted/reordered to produce the other.  Is there a mathematical term for this?

I can see one rotation matrix Rx is orthogonal, so I'm trying to come up with a term to show how by simply reordering these matrices, you get the others - and they must be orthogonal too.

Comment: Permutation. --

Comment: I suppose but.. I'm looking for something that shows how each permutation is done in the same way across column vectors.  For example column vectors [1,0,0] and [2,0,0] become [0,1,0] and [0,2,0] .. NOT [0,1,0] and [0,0,2]

Comment: Rotations form a group, so "composition" of two rotations yields another rotation.

Comment: Permutation: $P^{-1}RP$.

Comment: Apropos Jonas's answer, see [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permutation or, more precisely, conjugation by a permutation. Example:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix} \cos a&\sin a&0\\ -\sin a&\cos a&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&\cos a&\sin a\\ 0&-\sin a&\cos a\end{pmatrix}.
$$